# Counting numbers in an array

Tags: arrays, shell, unix, sh

I have been working on my script file and it is supposed to sum up a list of numbers and then count any numbers greater than 100 from the array.  When I execute the script, my count is blank because it is only counting the last number in the array, which is 17 and is less than 100.  I tested this by putting greater than 2 and when I run it, it displays the last number (17) only.  I'm pretty new to creating if/then statements in shell so if anything looks out of place or if I'm missing something please let me know. Thank you.

Below is my code:

```
#!/bin/sh
sum=0
array=(12 43 16 55 243 312 17)
for i in ${array[@]}; do
    echo $i;
    let sum+=$i
done
echo Total = $sum
if [ $i -gt 2 ];  then
    echo $i
fi
```

Comment: Do your check and keep count *in* the loop instead of after it.

Comment: `/bin/sh` is not guaranteed to support arrays; use `#!/bin/bash` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do your check and keep count in the loop instead of after it.

```
#!/bin/sh
sum=0
array=(12 43 16 55 243 312 17)
for i in "${array[@]}"; do
    echo "$i";
    let sum+="$i"
    if [ $i -gt 2 ];  then
        echo "$i is greater than 2"
    fi
done
echo "Total = $sum"
```

Answer (score 2):

You are using the variable `i` outside the `for` loop. The `if` clause should be inside the `for` loop.

```
count=0
for i in ${array[@]}; do
  if [ $i -gt 100 ]; then
    let count++
  fi
done
```